# How to click on a previously found sibling - python selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, html-table, tr

Is there any chance to click on the previous found sibling to open the link that is there?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By  
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
import openpyxl



# Load Excel data
excel_data = openpyxl.load_workbook("C:\Automatizace\data.xlsx")
sht = excel_data.active
cell_vz = sht.cell(row=2, column=2).value


try:
   wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
   find_user = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(),     '{cell_vz}')]")))


   previous_sibling = find_user.find_element(By.XPATH, "preceding-sibling::*[2]")
   previous_sibling.click()
   print("Najito: ", previous_sibling.text)



except Exception as error:
    print("Chyba při hledání uživatele:", error)

time.sleep(10)
```

`previous_sibling.click()` doesn't work for this...

website structure:

```
 <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="something">text</a>
    </td>
    <td></td> //this is what I need to click on
    <td></td>
    <td></td> //data from cell_vz
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Is there any chance to click on the previous found sibling to open the link that is there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is happened, because of incorrect usage of `preceding-sibling`.
To make in work, you should chain two selectors

```py
find_user = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(), '{cell_vz}')]//preceding-sibling::*[2]")))
```

I created example for your case, when clicking on needed element with `id=2` triggers background color change on element with `id=1`

```py
driver.get("https://inputnum.w3spaces.com/saved-from-Tryit-2023-08-17-a93u0.html")

td_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='1']//preceding-sibling::*[2]")
td_2.click()
```

If it is still doesn't work, probably, there is another reason why you aren't able to click.

Comment: I tried, but it didn't work

Comment: So, you need to provide complete DOM / resource. The problem in your case is not clicking on sibling itself, it is smth different.

Comment: I've provided the full code, you'll see it above.

Comment: @user304506333 I can't login to your system, so I can't see that element reproduce your issue

Comment: Have you tried `wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, f"//*[contains(text(), '{cell_vz}')]//preceding-sibling::*[2]"))).click()`?

Comment: This is the structure of one row in the table. I need to search by email in the third column, but I click on the second column.  

`<tr>
 <td>
  <a href="/Old/Pvdwad%2FNh6lLC">Bálek Pavel</a>
 </td>
 <td>
  <a href="/Old/pK87NhL%2BY%3D">Bálek Pavel</a>
 </td>
 <td>LDAP User</td>
 <td class="hidden-xs">pavel.balek@mail.cz</td>
 <td>Full</td>
 <td class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">pavel.balek@mail.cz</td>
 <td>1</td>
</tr>
        `

Comment: I still don't have a problem by clicking on element via locator `//*[contains(text(), '@mail.cz')]//preceding-sibling::*[2]`. Probably the issue is not locator itself - your element can be overlapped by something / not clickable, etc.

Comment: When I don't try to search by email, but by first and last name: Bálek Pavel, I manage to click on the link. I don't think there's a click error there, is there?